# Mirror apt repository that uses .bz2 files

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, mirroring, apt

I'm currently trying to set up a mirror for several apt-repositories that use Packages.bz2 files instead of regular gzip.

Unfortunately, apt-mirror on Ubuntu always tries to fetch Packages.gz files and fails.

Are there any options I can set? (running Ubuntu 12.04)

Answer (score 0):

It has been reported as a bug, and a patch has been released. You will have to wait for a new version/patched binary to be released, or you can compile it from patched source. [Here is the bug report and patch](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-mirror/+bug/184063).